# Timestamps changes zone in TestCase

Tags: unit-testing, pyspark, timezone, python-unittest

I am trying to test some functions which manipulates a pyspark data frame. I am using the `unittest` libary in Python to do so. I have the following code in my `setUp` function:

```
class TestMyClass(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.spark = (SparkSession
                    .builder
                    .master("local[*]")
                    .appName("Unit-tests")
                    .getOrCreate())

        self.data = [
            (datetime(2023, 4, 25, 0, 0, 0), "A", 100.5),
            (datetime(2023, 4, 26, 0, 0, 0), "A", 110.0),
            (datetime(2023, 4, 28, 0, 0, 0), "A", 105.0),
            (datetime(2023, 4, 25, 0, 0, 0), "B", 50.5),
            (datetime(2023, 4, 27, 0, 0, 0), "B", 55.5),
                ]

        self.schema = StructType([
                    StructField("time", TimestampType(), True), \
                    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
                    StructField("value", DoubleType(), True)
                ])

        self.df = spark.createDataFrame(
                    data=self.data,
                    schema=self.schema
                )
```

However, when I try and debug my code I have noticed that the timestamps in the `time` column are converted two hours back in time, so to `22:00:00`. But if I take the same code inside of the `setUp` function, and remove the `self.`, and executes in a notebook the time does not change. Is there some timezone sensitivity build in to the `TestCase` class? And how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Only unix epoch is not affected by the time zone since it's just a is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT).

Both your datetime object and Spark app will be affected by the timezone setting of your running machine. You can either:

1. Use unix epoch
2. Configure your spark app timezone by setting `spark.sql.session.timeZone` when you're using Spark SQL. For example you can set `Asia/Hong_Kong` when you need UTC+8 time zone.

Comment: Cab you elaborate on the two solutions, excatly how would you do it? :)